# HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception. NoClassDefFoundError : UpgradeUtil

Tags: java, websocket, tomcat7

We have been trying to build a simple web application using Tomcat and the Websockets. The system is functional on localhost. The problem started when we tried to deploy the web application on the Server (Debian Linux, running Tomcat 7.0.52). The application runs perfectly fine on localhost (Windows 7, running Tomcat 7.0.52). Methods suggested so far for error 500 have been mainly to check the jars in the lib folder of the tomcat. (That weirdly doesn't seem to be the issue as all the jars seems to be present in the lib folder. I even extracted un-jarred the wesocket jar and checked if the class UpgradeUtil was present. It was!).

We get this error when accessing the site from the browser.

> HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception
>    type Exception report  
>   message Filter execution threw an exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:50)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 logs.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.52

And this error in the error logs.

> Apr 3, 2014 9:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/CrossGames] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:50)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:193)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:732)

We tried

1. Checking the jars (tomcat-websocket.jar and  websocket-api.jar are present)
2. Checking Versions. Versions of the tomcat installed are same as on our system.
3. Reinstalling tomcat

Your insights and views will be greatly helpful to us. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

This problem got fixed with reinstallation of tomcat. I am afraid if this is of any help to others.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, I just restart the Servlet (Online tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil may be present, but the exception means the was a problem during its initialization process.

Check for the presence of these classes:

org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.Constants;
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsHandshakeResponse;
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointServer;

Comment: I checked for these classes. They are all present. Still trying to find a solution ..